# Python/Pyside layout after pyside-uic, doesn't look like in Qtdesigner

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I've got problem with pyside. When I was developing my simple app I created Ui in Qtdesigner and converted it to .py file with pyside-uic. This ui was evolving at the time my project was getting bigger. Everything has worked fine until I added one button. Now in my qtdesigner everything looks fine, but when I implement it in my code some wild margins and spacings appears. How to overcome this?

Layout in qtdesigner and list of my widgets:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPq0I.jpg
Layout in my program:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Kqe.jpg

Comment: It looks like the layout of the main window has been broken. Can you check that it's there in Designer and that the buttons aren't just sitting in the right spot coincidentally?

Comment: @figs In qtDesigner layout is not borken. I could resize the window in editting mode and in preview and everything stays where it should stay. Also I updated my question with screenshot with all my widgets and added qt code from qtdesigner.

Comment: @Jedrus7. The code you posted is C++ and completely irrelevant. Please remove it and post the whole `ui` file instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution to this problem. It actually changes layout a little bit but with that trick It looks better. So this textedit at the bottom of my program can't be under left tablewidget.
Picture representing what I'm saying:

[Current view of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XslZf.jpg)

But stil I don't know why this is happening.